# Изменение имени папки python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

у мена такой вопрос как переименовать имя папки в большом каталоге

пример

```
n = ввод имя искомой папки

m = ввод нового имени искомой папки
```

цикл, который самостоятельно ищет эту папку в каталоге и потом меняет имя по заданным переменным

```
папка1\папка2\папка3\папка4\папка5\папка6

os.rename(n,m)
```

Какой цикл нужно прописать, чтобы он самостоятельно находил папку, которую нужно переименовать

Answer (score 1):

Пример поиск и переименования через `pathlib.Path`.

- `'.'` -- текущая активная директория
- Для своего задачи зададите свой путь, откуда нужно начинать поиск

Пример:

```
# Создаем папки для тестирования
import os.path
os.makedirs('./dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4', exist_ok=True)

from pathlib import Path

n = 'dir3'
m = 'new_dir3'

# Рекурсивный поиск
items = list(Path('.').rglob(n))

# Если нашли папку
if items:
    path = items[0]
    path.rename(path.parent / m)
```